# Resize gui elements based on monitor resolution

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, resize

I am developing a `C#` application and I have this problem:

Now when I finished my app I tried using it from different monitors and I had the re-sizing problem. I have group boxes, list views, labels, buttons etc. I tried Anchoring them down, up, left etc.. the best behavior I got by anchoring everything to the left, because I don't really care about making it bigger than it is, it looks good even if a maximize on a 23' monitor, the problem is when I try shrinking lower than it's original size:

- the form starts shrinking and the scroll appears so I can see all the form using the scroll (right - left , because the problem is with the width in my case) and it's not how I would like it to work
- the next things I would like to appear, when a shrink it lower than it's original size, every item in the form to get smaller so everything will fit in
- autoscaling and autosize didn't work for me, maybe I didn't use it well..
- anchoring top, left, right, bottom in function of where would I put them worked well when growing but when I shrink everything get's on top of other items ( they overlay )

So, guys, do you have any idea or solution of how could I get that beautiful scaling when I resize?

Comment: Maybe include some code, as your question now is very broad.

Comment: I guess this is a WinForms app. It should be WinForms... because you would not have troubles like this using WPF instead :)

Answer (score 0):

WPF Example:

**Note**: Code is not tested. Its a prototype for how to implement responsive UI in WPF application.

WPF application contains one MainWindow. This mainwidows contains Pages, where each page is one Screen.

```
namespace Example
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += window_SizeChanged;
    }
    LoginScreen screen1= new LoginScreen)();
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {           


    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainFrame.addPage(screen1);
    }

    private void setAppConfiguration()
    {

    }
    private void window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Gets called when even windows size got changed. On each trigger we         are calling resize() on that respective screen.
        screen1.resize();
    }
}
}


<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
     xmlns:toastinet="clr-namespace:ToastinetWPF;assembly=ToastinetWPF"
    Title="IGNITOR" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded" 
    Name="window"
WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
<Grid Name="maingrid" >
        <Grid Name="frameGrid"> 
            <Frame Name="mainFrame" />
        </Grid>                       
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Window>




namespace Example.Screens
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for LoginPage.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class LoginScreen : Page
{
    int count =0;
    public LoginScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void resizePage()
    {
         //Put all yout UI Logic here on resize..
         errorlabel.Content = count + "";
         count++;
    }
}
}


<src:Page x:Class="Example.Screens"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Example.Screens"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1200" Title="LoginPage">

<Grid>
    <Label Name="errorlabel" Content="Example"/>
</Grid>
</src:Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, well the application wasn't so large, but the monitor I tried was old and cropped the picture, I tried from a newer laptop and it's alright, so I don't care if I doesn't work on every type of monitor ( when the above is old old )